What do the Instruction Statistics fields in Nsight Compute mean? How do they relate to elapsed cycles?

In my example, what is the meaning of 'Executed Instructions'? According to the literal meaning， it would mean how many instruction have been executed.
But how does it relate to the total run  time (74.35ms, 166170948cycle)?
And what is the meaning of 'Avg. Executed Instructions Per Scheduler'?
Why is 'Executed Instructions Per Scheduler' 5 times smaller than 'Executed Instructions'?

I think you missread the "Executed Instructions Per Scheduler" due to its two decimal places. It is actually a factor ~500 smaller than 'Executed Instructions'.

The RTX 4090 has 128 SMs with 4 warp schedulers each, i.e. 512 warp schedulers in total. That is exactly the factor between the two numbers.

The NSight Compute documentation tells us :

Instructions Executed
Number of times the source (instruction) was executed per individual warp, independent of the number of participating threads within each warp.

This is a count over all warps in the launch grid of the physical GPU instructions executed. These are not CUDA instructions or even PTX instructions, but the concrete GPU's streaming multiprocessor instructions, (e.g. IADD.3; see this question for discussion of that particular family of SASS instructions). The count disregards conditional execution, i.e. if a warp has an then branch of an if block, with 5 instructions to execute, but two of threads have already exited - the contribution to the count would still be exactly 5 instructions.
Note that instruction execution time (usually) varies:

Different instructions require SM functional unit activity for a different amount of time
Load instructions will have different latencies depending on the time it takes to complete the read, e.g. depending on cache situations, bank conflicts for shared memory etc.
There is always the time to wait before an instruction is scheduled for execution
... on the other hand, while some warps are waiting, others may execute their own instructions ("latency hiding")

So while the number of instructions executed is generally positively-correlated with the execution time or the elapsed number of clock cycles, that correlation is quite complex.
